# VB.NET get directory of a file opened in my program

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that makes it so that all files with the ".whatever" extension open with my program:

```
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(".whatever\shell\open\command", True) Is Nothing Then
    Dim icotouse As String = Path.GetTempPath() & "\whatever.ico"
    My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(".whatever").SetValue("", "whatever", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
    My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("whatever\shell\open\command").SetValue("", Application.ExecutablePath, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
    My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("whatever\DefaultIcon").SetValue("", icotouse)
End If
```

Now when the user double clicks the ".whatever" file, it will open in my program.

How do I get the directory of where the ".whatever" file was when I open it in my program? For example, user clicks a file on their desktop [C:\Users\Example\Desktop\file.whatever] and when they click it, it opens up in my program, and I can assign a variable name to that directory?

Comment: "whatever" as shown would refer to the path for the app, not the file opened in the program. If the ".whatever" is opened in your program, how can you not know where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make Windows pass the path of the file to your program. This is done by adding `%1` to the `command` key's default value.

Change your code that creates the `command` key to this:

```
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("whatever\shell\open\command").SetValue("", Application.ExecutablePath & " %1", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
```

Secondly, to get the path of the file sent to your program, you'd use for example `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`.

Put this somewhere like in the `Form_Load` event:

```
Dim Arguments() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

If Arguments.Length > 1 Then 'If there's more than one argument, it means that something (like a file) was passed to your application.

End If
```

Now, the `If`-statement checks if a parameter was sent to your application. To get the path of your file you'd simply put something like this inside it:

```
Dim FilePath As String = Arguments(1)
'Will give you for example: C:\Users\Example\Desktop\file.whatever
```

But if you want to get the file's directory, you can do the following below:

```
Dim FileDirectory As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath)
'Will give you for example: C:\Users\Example\Desktop
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you're an absolute life saver!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Command Line Arguments

You can do that with something like this

```
Dim arguments As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
Console.WriteLine("GetCommandLineArgs: {0}", String.Join(", ", arguments))
```

Also you might want to look at this MSDN link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I dont understand... How do i pass the files directory as an argument?