# How to get the path of selected folder in vb .net?

Tags: vb.net

I have created a small application in vb .net to load all the files present inside the current folder where my application is running.  I want to customize this application in such a manner that, when the user right click on any folder my application name also should appear in that menu.  When the user click's that option, all the files present inside that corresponding folder should get listed.

I have achieved this partially.  I have added my application to the right click menu item of all folders.  But when I click my application name, all the files present in the parent directory is listed.  I want to customize my coding to receive the path of the selected folder.  So, how to do that?

Comment: Without seeing your actua lcode it is hard to help you. edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.NET get directory of a file opened in my program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540593/vb-net-get-directory-of-a-file-opened-in-my-program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a whole tutorial on MSDN: [Verbs and File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> For example, the open verb normally launches a program to open a file. The command string typically looks as follows:
>   `"My Program.exe" "%1"`

You can get the parameters by the code below:

```
Public Sub Main(ByVal cmdArgs() As String)
    If cmdArgs.Length > 0 Then
        'Process the command.
        'cmdArgs(0) is program name
        'cmdArgs(1) is the path of your folder / file.
    End If
End Sub
```

For `Windows Forms`, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306903/how-to-find-the-main-entry-point-in-a-vb-net-winforms-app) .You'll need a function like below:

```
Public Sub Main(ByVal cmdArgs() As String)
    'Process cmdArgs here (same as above)
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
    Application.Run(New Form1)
End Sub
```

Comment: It works on Console Application.  But how to do that on Windows Application?

Comment: I have tried the above technique you have specified.  But my Main() Function didn't get called at all.  I have provide overloaded constructor to receive the argument.  But that also didn't works.

Comment: Remove the constructor with no parameters.

Comment: Now only I have referred to the link you specified.  It gets worked.  Thanks a lot!